# For loop iteration - Checkbox auto increment by no

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a checkbox group like below. It will be increment for 20 to 30 groups.

Instead of write jQuery like below for each checkbox group, is it possible to make through for loop iteration?

I tried through loop, but its not working as expected.

```js
$('.checkbox-1 .done-check').change(function() {
  $('.checkbox-1 .done-check').prop('checked', false);
  $(this).prop('checked', true);
});

$('.checkbox-2 .done-check').change(function() {
  $('.checkbox-2 .done-check').prop('checked', false);
  $(this).prop('checked', true);
});

$('.checkbox-3 .done-check').change(function() {
  $('.checkbox-3 .done-check').prop('checked', false);
  $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check checkbox-1">
  <label class="form-check-label">
            <input name="checklist-done" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input done-check"> Yes
        </label>
  <label class="form-check-label">
            <input name="checklist-done" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input done-check"> No
        </label>
</div>

<div class="form-check checkbox-2">
  <label class="form-check-label">
            <input name="checklist-done" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input done-check"> Yes
        </label>
  <label class="form-check-label">
            <input name="checklist-done" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input done-check"> No
        </label>
</div>

<div class="form-check checkbox-3">
  <label class="form-check-label">
            <input name="checklist-done" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input done-check"> Yes
        </label>
  <label class="form-check-label">
            <input name="checklist-done" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input done-check"> No
        </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of re-inventing a radio button... just use radio buttons.

Comment: why you want to do this if radio button is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to loop at all.  You just need to use contextual lookups correctly.

```js
$('.done-check').on('change', function(){
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).closest('div.form-check').find('.done-check').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check checkbox-1">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input name="checklist-done" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input done-check"> Yes
    </label>
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input name="checklist-done" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input done-check"> No
    </label>
</div>

<div class="form-check checkbox-2">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input name="checklist-done" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input done-check"> Yes
    </label>
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input name="checklist-done" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input done-check"> No
    </label>
</div>

<div class="form-check checkbox-3">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input name="checklist-done" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input done-check"> Yes
    </label>
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input name="checklist-done" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input done-check"> No
    </label>
</div>
```

When a checkbox is checked, you find the parent `form-check` wrapping the grouped checkboxes.  You then find the nested checkboxes, exclude the one just checked, and then mark the rest unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iterating will be much more efficient.  Also, let's clean up your selectors a little.  Selectors like `$('.checkbox-3 .done-check')` work but are inefficient because jQuery reads them from right to left.  Instead use `$('.checkbox-3').find('.done-check')`.

For the loop:

```
var max = 30; // or how ever you determine it
for(var i = 1; i <= max; i++)
{
    $('.checkbox-' + i).find('.done-check').change(function(){
        $('.checkbox-' + i).find('.done-check').prop('checked',false);
        $(this).prop('checked',true);
    });
}
```

Now, I don't know why you have the two different lines there inside the function because they both target the same element but whatever your reason, that is *one* way to do the loop.